# "From this Saturday," from this Saturday on," or "as of this Saturday"?

Tags: prepositions

Would you tell me if all the following sentences are natural and grammatically correct?

> **From** this Saturday I'm going to do more exercise.
>
> **From** this Saturday **on** I'm going to do more exercise.
>
> **As of** this Saturday I'm going to do more exercise.

To they all sound correct and natural, but I'd like to know what English native speakers think about them. If some of them are unnatural, could you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is a bit vague. I (a native AmE speaker) would probably say "Starting this Saturday, . . ."

The second is fine.

The third is OK, but "as of" often refers to events that happened before that time. E.g.: "All of my friends had gotten married as of 2019." To be clearer, I might write: "As of this Saturday I'm going to **start doing** more exercise."

Also, the auxiliary verb "do" is not needed in any of the sentences and would usually be omitted.